# Popular ClientDataSet com JSON trunca os dados em 255 caracteres

Tags: json, delphi

Estou tentando passar um JSON para um TClientDataSet utilizando a seguinte função:

```
procedure JsonToDataset(aDataset : TDataSet; aJSON : string);
var
  JObj: TJSONObject;
  JArr: TJSONArray;
  vConv : TCustomJSONDataSetAdapter;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if (aJSON = EmptyStr) then
  begin
    Exit;
  end;

  JArr := nil;
  JObj := nil;

  try
    JArr := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(aJSON) as TJSONArray;
  except
    JObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(aJSON) as TJSONObject;
  end;

  vConv := TCustomJSONDataSetAdapter.Create(Nil);

  try
    vConv.Dataset := aDataset;

    if JObj <> nil then
      vConv.UpdateDataSet(JObj)
    else
      vConv.UpdateDataSet(JArr);

  finally
    vConv.Free;
    JObj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Porém, quando tenho um campo grande, a função trunca minha string em 255 caracteres. Exemplo de JSON:

```
{
  "string": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus convallis risus, nec posuere nisl gravida vitae. Duis elementum augue nec condimentum rutrum. Aliquam sodales, dolor at laoreet pharetra, tortor eros efficitur eros, vel euismod sem nulla quis erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut vitae congue lectus, et sodales velit. Cras suscipit pulvinar dolor ut consequat. Praesent eget pellentesque justo. In at maximus lectus, posuere mattis felis."
}
```

Tem alguma forma de contornar este problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Classe `TCustomJSONDataSetAdapter` identifica e cria por padrão o Tipo dos campos.

No caso de conteúdo `string` será criado por padrão um campo do tipo `WideStrig` de 255 caracteres.

O Ideal é você criar o campo antes da conversão com um tamanho maior que o criado no processo de conversão.

Utilize um `Blob` se não sabe o tamanho que será enviado.

Edit:

Ao invés de usar o `TDataSet`, utilize uma `TClientDataSet` pois, a facilidade de criar os campos será muito maior:

```
var
  i    : Integer;
  JObj : TJSONObject;
begin
  if (aJSON <> EmptyStr) then
  begin
    JObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(aJSON) as TJSONObject;

    aDataset.Close;
    aDataset.FieldDefs.Clear; //Limpa os Campos Existentes

    for i := 0 to Pred(JObj.Size) do
    begin
      //Chave: JObj.Get(i).JsonString.Value
      if (Length(JObj.Get(i).JsonValue.Value) > 250) then
      begin
        aDataset.FieldDefs.Add(JObj.Get(i).JsonString.Value, ftBlob);
      end
      else
      begin
        aDataset.FieldDefs.Add(JObj.Get(i).JsonString.Value, ftString, 255);
      end;
    end;

    aDataset.CreateDataSet;

    for i := 0 to Pred(JObj.Size) do
    begin
      //Valor: JObj.Get(i).JsonValue.Value
      aDataset.Insert;
      aDataset.FieldByName(JObj.Get(i).JsonString.Value).AsString := JObj.Get(i).JsonValue.Value;
      aDataset.Post;
    end;

    JObj.Free;
  end;
```

Esta é uma alternativa para que não seja necessário usar a classe `TCustomJSONDataSetAdapter` que possui um padrão a ser seguido, claro, é possível modificar esta classe, mas ai é a nível de IDE e não vale a pena, pois perderia este progresso em uma próxima atualização!

Comment: Neste caso eu perderia a dinâmica que eu quero com a ideia, pois eu não sei qual o nome do campo que virá do REST. Desta forma, não posso criar o campo antes.

Comment: Da mesma forma amigo, terá que ler o Json antes de converter e criar os campos dinamicamente! Pois, é um padrão da Classe.

Comment: Quando eu faço o ``UpdateDataSet`` ele reconstrói o DataSet. Tem alguma forma de fazer isso melhor? Mesmo que não use o TCustomJSONDataSetAdapter?

Comment: Ai teria que ser "TOTALMENTE dinâmico na mão", ou seja, o que eu disse anteriormente, percorrer o Objeto Json e reconhecer as chaves, e ai sim Criar os Campos.

Comment: Tentei desta forma (http://collabedit.com/2e6pf), mas após o Update, ele apaga e recria meus campos. Estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: A forma que você tentou é valida, mas o resultado você ja viu, ele apaga. Sem opção, tente fazer o que lhe informei antes, cria os campos dinamicamente com base nas Chaves do JSON

Comment: Júnior, teria como me gerar um pequeno exemplo de como gerar os campos dinamicamente, por favor?

Comment: Estou no celular rsrsrs, chegar em casa edito a Resposta.

Comment: Implementei a solução e o resultado saiu conforme eu precisava! Obrigado!
Mas tem algum motivo especial pro TCustomJSONDataSetAdapter 
 não alterar automaticamente o campo para ftMemo?

Comment: Não possui, ele prefere o ftWidString por padrão!